# Simple Web Server Implementation: GoLang

Tags: go, webserver

I am trying to implement a simple web server using Go. I expected "Hello World" to be displayed on the client's browser at the URL "http://127.0.0.1.12000/".

I have tried the following code but ended up with errors.

```
package main

import "net"
import "fmt"
import "bufio"

// import "strings"
// only needed below for sample processing

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Launching server...")

    // listen on all interfaces
    ln, err := net.Listen("tcp", ":12000")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Launching error1...")
        return
    }
    // run loop forever (or until ctrl-c)
    for {
        // accept connection on port
        conn, err := ln.Accept()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Launching error2...")
            return
        }

        // will listen for message to process ending in newline (\n)
        message, err := bufio.NewReader(conn).ReadString('\n')

        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Launching error3...")
            newmessage := "Hello World!"
            conn.Write([]byte(newmessage + "\n"))
            return
        }

        // output message received
        fmt.Print("Message Received:", string(message))

        // sample process for string received
        newmessage := "Hello World!"
        conn.Write([]byte(newmessage + "\n"))
    }
}
```

When I tried to execute the code, the command line shows the following, but there is no output on browser..

```
Launching server...
Message Received:GET / HTTP/1.1
Message Received:GET / HTTP/1.1
```

Am I missing anything? Did I make any mistakes?

Comment: Hm.. seems to have worked for me... Although it might be because you're trying to go to `http://127.0.0.1.12000` instead of `http://127.0.0.1:12000`. You have a period instead a colon that separates the host from the port.

Comment: Is there a reason you're trying to reinvent the standard library? net/http makes all this trivial.

Comment: You can print any `error` you receive instead of "Launching error<n>...". This may help shed some light on your error.

Comment: If you want to reimplement HTTP to access your server via a browser, then your server should answer with HTTP (i.e. proper headers and body) and not just some random string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to add some information here.. That that isn't a simple server that you're writing. You're trying to write an HTTP server without the [`net/http`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/) package. This is nontrivial. Perhaps you want an echo server instead?

Your browser wants a properly formatted HTTP response. That means you can't just write a random string to the connection and expect it to know what to do with it. Here is a [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) to the HTTP protocol description (I don't intend to describe an entire protocol in a SO answer).

If you want just a bare bones answer that should work:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8;
Content-Length: LENGTH OF BODY HERE

BODY
```

Note that headers are separated by `\r\n` and the last header is followed by two: `\r\n\r\n`.

So this:

```
conn.Write([]byte("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n"))
conn.Write([]byte("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\r\n"))
newmessage := "Hello World!"
conn.Write([]byte("Content-Length: " + strconv.Itoa(len(newmessage)) + "\r\n\r\n"))
conn.Write([]byte(newmessage + "\n"))
```

Also, I guess since this is a protocol issue I could also let you know that the typical HTTP port is 80 and the alternative/testing one is 8080. Just some added convention for your knowledge I guess.

Comment: `the typical HTTP port is 80 and the alternative/testing one is 8080` Well... the first statement there is true. The second one isn't, really. A lot of servers do use `8080` (mainly in the Java world, haven't seen it as much elsewhere), but that's because of the larger informal convention of simply catenating the port number to create an alternate / testing port number (i.e. running an SSH server on `2222` instead of `22`, or an SMTP server on `2525` instead of `25`). There's nothing actually special about `8080`.

Comment: Other examples of the 'str(port) * 2` trend include port 2121 (FTP proxy) and 5353 (mDNS).

Comment: The second statement is true. It is registered on [iana](http://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml?&page=108) as http-alt.